# ionic cordova build android and jdk version error

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

i try to generate an android build with the command *ionic cordova build android*
i'm using

- gradle 7.4.2
- cordova-android 10.1.2
- jdk 11.0.19
- sdk 31 with build-tools 31.0.0 (with copy of dx and dx.jar from 30.0.3)
  with
  *ionic cordova requirements* i have this error :

> Requirements check results for android: Java JDK: installed 11.0.19
> Android SDK: installed true Android target: not installed  Command
> failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target Exception in thread
> "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema   at
> com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
> at
> com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
> at
> com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
> at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
> at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> ... 5 more Gradle: installed /opt/gradle/gradle-7.4.2/bin/gradle

if i use jdk8, the requirements are ok and i see android targets
but can't build android version 31 with it (missing libraries)

i have all required variables in my sh (JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_SDK_ROOT) and paths : gradle/bin, sdk/tools, sdk/tools/bin

with sdk-30 and builds tools 30.0.3 the build works, but not with sdk-31,if i try to build it, i have an error for missing java libraries

BUT, if i use directly gradle with *gradle bundleRelease* it works perfectly with android-31 target and the signed apk works on my phone

it is a old project and many packages are outdated.
it is possible to fix it for using good command (ionic cordova build android?)

Comment: You need to make sure you have the update dependencies since you sate the project is old. NPM, Node, Gradle all need to be updated. check the docs for what version you need to be on.

Comment: finally the build works with not all requierements, but it generate an apk file, don't accepted by android platform. i'm resigned to to ng build + gradle bundleRelease + jarsigner + zipalign, or bundletool. thx @StackoverBlows